# How can I use Mockito to verify calls with ByteBuffer arguments?

Tags: java, junit, mockito, bytebuffer

I'm trying to create a test for a library that uses `ByteBuffer`.

A simplified version is here:

```
public class ByteBufferTest {
    public static class Stuff {
        public void doSomething(Target target, ByteBuffer buffer) {
            ByteBuffer slice = buffer.slice();
            slice.limit(1);
            target.accept(slice);
            target.command();
            buffer.position(1);
            target.accept(buffer);
            // do more with the buffer
            buffer.get();
        }
    }

    private interface Target {
        void accept(ByteBuffer slice);
        void command();
    }

    @Test
    public void doSomething() {
        final Stuff stuff = new Stuff();
        final Target mockTarget = Mockito.mock(Target.class);

        stuff.doSomething(mockTarget, ByteBuffer.wrap(new byte[]{1, 2, 3, 4}));

        InOrder inOrder = Mockito.inOrder(mockTarget);
        inOrder.verify(mockTarget).accept(ByteBuffer.wrap(new byte[]{1}));
        inOrder.verify(mockTarget).command();
        inOrder.verify(mockTarget).accept(ByteBuffer.wrap(new byte[]{2, 3, 4}));
    }
}
```

This works fine if the `doSomething` method does *not* have `buffer.get();` at the end.

This test fails because by the time the `inOrder.verify(mockTarget).accept(ByteBuffer.wrap(new byte[]{2, 3, 4}));` is called, the argument passed in was modified by the `buffer.get()` call afterward.

Is there a way to verify the contents of that buffer at the time of invocation?

Comment: doesn't that mean that the test is validly failing; if the `doSomething` method calls `buffer.get()` the resulting ByteBuffer would have an additional element removed.

Comment: At the time of the call to `accept`, it contains the correct data. The contract of `doSomething` is precisely that the `accept` method is called with a subset of the data, and the data buffer, but `accept` doesn't own the buffer after it returns.   The real use-case is a bit more complex (its actually parsing the content of the `ByteBuffer`, and splitting it into 3 parts, the pre-data, the command, and the post-data.  It then is responsible for making sure the post-data is consumed.

Comment: Why is target a mock, but buffer is not? That seems strange.

Comment: The main reason I'm treating the buffer is not-a-mock, is that ByteBuffer's are pretty "primitive" like, except that they are mutable.  You probably wouldn't mock a String instance, or even primitive wrappers. So to me it is okay to not mock buffer.

Answer (score 1):

Option A. If it's hard to test, maybe there is also a problem with the implementation? Is every `Target` supposed to instantly act on this buffer? Maybe we just hand over another slice on the second invocation:

```java
target.accept(buffer.slice());
```

Option B. Don't test the plattform, just test the interaction:

```java
    @Test
    public void doSomething1() {
        final Stuff stuff = new Stuff();
        final Target mockTarget = mock(Target.class);
        final ByteBuffer buffer = mock(ByteBuffer.class);
        final ByteBuffer slice = mock(ByteBuffer.class);
        given(buffer.slice()).willReturn(slice);

        stuff.doSomething(mockTarget, buffer);

        final InOrder inOrder = Mockito.inOrder(mockTarget);
        inOrder.verify(mockTarget).accept(slice);
        inOrder.verify(mockTarget).command();
        inOrder.verify(mockTarget).accept(buffer);
    }
```

Option C. Your own test double implementation of `ByteBuffer` would normally  give you full control, unless the Buffer/ByteBuffer/HeapByteBuffer class hierarchy wouldn't be as test-unfriendly as it is.

Comment: Thanks for the thoughtful response. This is performance critical code, so I want to avoid unnecessary slices if possible. Overall, being able to verify argument state at invocation time seems like it should be supported by Mockito.

Comment: @Daniel I've added two more thoughts to my answer.

Comment: The code snippet you've shown is unnecessarily coupled to the implementation details of doSomething.  doSomething's contract is send data, send command, send more data.  It doesn't (nor should it) specify whether that data is a slice, the passed in buffer, or a constructor bytebuffer.

Comment: In any case, I decided for now to go with changing my code to just reuse the earlier slice.

Comment: Ok. yes, in the end, the specific interactions to be asserted depend on your requirements. Reducing these slice() calls sounds like an improvement.